# Chose a random paperclip attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have "foo" controller that, among other things has 3 paperclip attached images.

foo.image1, foo.image2 and foo.image3

What is the best way to render in a view one random attachment that gets refreshed every time the page is reloaded?

--EDIT---

Ok, this is not very elegant code but at least avoids using send and serves my purpose.

```
    @a = foo.image1(:thumb) 
    @b = foo.image2(:thumb)
    @c = foo.image3(:thumb)

    @rand = ([@a, @b, @c].sample)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you can do something like:

```
@image = foo.send([:image1, :image2, :image3].sample)
```

What this is doing is randomly selecting (sampling) a symbol corresponding to the name of the images, and then sending that symbol to `foo` to execute. The result is stored in the instance variable, which can then be used in your view.

As long as this is done every time someone hits your action (e.g if it's in a `show` action or something) then it will always randomly select a new image, even on refresh.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. Anyway using it I'm not able to use the paperclip functionality, such as (:thumb). For example @image(:thumb) will rise a syntax error.

Comment: Actually this is becoming problematic since most of my projects relies on the paperclip functionality and the send method is preventing me to take advantage of that.

Comment: Interesting. What is the error message exactly? The result of using `send` should be the same as just typing `foo.image1` and should work fine.

Comment: Ok, the controller looks like this: `@randimage = @r2012.send([:image1, :image2, :image3].sample)`. The view looks like this: `<%= image_tag @randimage(:thumb) %>`. Here is the error: `/home/andrea/misc/rails/lacollezionedianna/app/views/static_pages/outfits.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
...append= ( image_tag @randimage(:thumb) );@output_buffer.safe...
.../static_pages/outfits.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
... image_tag @randimage(:thumb) );@output_buffer.safe_concat('...` Thank you